# First form of database normalization?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an ER diagram that I want normalize. But I'm not sure if I normalize it correctly. Do I need to include every primary key to table the columns?

[image: Here is my database ER Diagram]

And here is my SQL Server code for my table. I'm not sure if this correct:
http://rextester.com/BCA95581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), a relation (table) is in first normal form:

> First normal form (1NF) is a property of a relation in a relational database. A relation is in first normal form if and only if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic (indivisible) values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain. The first definition of the term, in a 1971 conference paper by Edgar Codd, defined a relation to be in first normal form when none of its domains have any sets as elements.

So just the raw structure as you show it in the ER diagram doesn't really suffice to know if the tables are in 1NF - it depends on the **domain** and the possible data types. Just make sure that

**(1)** each attribute (column in every table) can only hold **atomic values** (no arrays, lists, objects, comma-separated values  etc.)

**(2)** no column can ever hold more than 1 of these values

If you're using the basic data types of SQL Server, then you should be fine.